# how to do a @GET in RXJava in android

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I just need to do a @GET for the [following endpoint](http://iwg-testapi.azurewebsites.net/stem/funds) but not sure the syntax, here is my code:

```
public interface GithubService {
    String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "https://api.github.com";
    String SERVICE_FUNDS_ENDPOINT = "http://iwg-testapi.azurewebsites.net";


    // this works fine
    @GET("/users/{login}")
    Observable<Github> getUser(@Path("login") String login);

    //here is the problem:
    @GET("/stem/funds")
    Observable<Funds> getFunds(@Path("funds") String login);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a RxJava issue but a Retrofit.

I think the issue is on the GET annotation, as you want to use the path param.

```
@GET("/stem/{funds}") Observable<Funds> getFunds(@Path("funds")
```

(Notice that I add {} around funds because I want to use it at the path param)

You may want to check the Retrofit documentation.